# Tycho mirroring errors out with on the Eclipse GEF (5.x) repo

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm simply trying to mirror and package the following repository Eclipse GEF (5.x) - https://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/5.4.0_gef-master_6893/

But I'm encountering a strange error I've never seen before:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-p2-extras-plugin:4.0.4:mirror 
(default) on project gef: Error during mirroring: Mirroring failed: Messages while mirroring 
artifact descriptors.: [Failed to transfer artifact packed: 
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.geometry.doc,5.0.3.202209120200.: [Download of 
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.geometry.doc,5.0.3.202209120200 failed on repository 
https://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/5.4.0_gef-master_6893. Retrying. : [No 
location for packed: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.geometry.doc,5.0.3.202209120200.]; Artifact 
not found: packed: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.geometry.doc,5.0.3.202209120200.]] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-p2-extras-plugin:4.0.4:mirror (default) on project gef: Error 
during mirroring
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
```

When I add that update-site repo into an Eclipse, it seems to read fine and displays the categories and contents from the "Available Software" wizard.

As far as my configurations, I'm trying to build this using Java 17, Eclipse 4.24, Apache 3.9.5, and Tycho 4.0.4.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>mirror</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    <repository>
                        <url>https://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/5.4.0_gef-master_6893/</url>
                    </repository>
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a configuration I can add to bypass this or is there an issue with the GEF repository that I would need to report?

EDIT: I did see this config to set `<ignoreErrors>true</ignoreErrors>`, but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.